# Pandas: Sort dataframe correctly with German umlauts, upper/lowercase and numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**I have this dataframe (all strings):**

```
      to_sort data
0     Belgien   a2
1      Zürich   b2
2    dänemark   c2
3          20   d2
4         100   e2
5  Österreich   f2
```

I want to sort it so that German umlauts are correct, also lowercase and numbers are correct:

```
      to_sort data
3          20   d2
4         100   e2
0     Belgien   a2
2    dänemark   c2
5  Österreich   f2
1      Zürich   b2
```

**Here is my code to generate the dataframe and result:**

```
import io, pandas as pd

t = io.StringIO("""
to_sort|data
Belgien|a2
Zürich|b2
dänemark|c2
20|d2
100|e2
Österreich|f2""")
df = pd.read_csv(t, sep='|')

df = df.sort_values(by='to_sort', key=lambda col: col.str.lower().str.normalize('NFD'))
```

The result is almost correct, but the numbers are sorted in the wrong order, 20 should be before 200:

```
      to_sort data
4         100   e2
3          20   d2
0     Belgien   a2
2    dänemark   c2
5  Österreich   f2
1      Zürich   b2
```

**How can I fix the number sorting, while maintaining all the other characteristics?**

Comment: `'100'<'20'` will evaluate to `True` due to the way python does string comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use solution from last sample data in [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
from natsort import index_natsorted

f = lambda col: np.argsort(index_natsorted(col.str.lower().str.normalize('NFD')))
df = df.sort_values(by='to_sort', key=f )
print (df)
      to_sort data
3          20   d2
4         100   e2
0     Belgien   a2
2    dänemark   c2
5  Österreich   f2
1      Zürich   b2
```

Comment: That works, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Just append `.str.pad(max(col.str.len())`:

```
key = lambda col: col.str.lower().str.normalize('NFD').str.pad(max(col.str.len()))
df = df.sort_values(by='to_sort', key=key)
print(df)

# Output
      to_sort data
3          20   d2
4         100   e2
0     Belgien   a2
1      Zürich   b2
2    dänemark   c2
5  Österreich   f2
```

Comment: Sorry, in German sorting Österreich (O) comes before Zürich.